# are there alternative webinterfaces to ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

I think the groups/roster management of the default webadmin plugin is kind of unintuitive so I am looking for alternatives that resemble quite a bit more the interface of for example openfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no alternatives, but depending on your XMPP client you can do a whole lot of things from there when logged in as an administrative user.

Comment: Can you name any particular client that allows one to run administrative commands on the XMPP server (provided, of course, that's the admin user)? Thanks!